# MKMapView is misaligned to its region property

Tags: cocoa, mkmapview, mapkit

I want to display a certain map region in MKMapView but when I put a rectangular overlay on the map with the very same parameters it is displayed misaligned vertically. It looks good enough close to the equator but the misalignment is increasing with the latitude and the span.

This is for a mac app, but it should be the same for iOS.

This is my relevant code:

```
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latCenter, lonCenter), MKCoordinateSpanMake(mapWidthY, mapWidthX));
self.radarMap.region = mapRegion;
CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinates[4];

coordinates[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latCenter+mapWidthY/2, lonCenter+mapWidthX/2);
coordinates[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latCenter+mapWidthY/2, lonCenter-mapWidthX/2);
coordinates[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latCenter-mapWidthY/2, lonCenter-mapWidthX/2);
coordinates[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latCenter-mapWidthY/2, lonCenter+mapWidthX/2);
self.boundaryOverlay = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coordinates count:4];
[self.radarMap addOverlay:self.boundaryOverlay];
```

**It shows this:** (Notice the blue rect overlay is moved up so the upper region is not displayed):
[image]

**Instead of something like this:** (I'm aware of that it is displayed in aspect fill):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the region property of an MKMapView object, MapKit adjusts the value of the region property so that it matches the actual region that's visible. That means that the actual value of region isn't going to be exactly what you assigned to it. So instead of creating the polygon using the region that you assigned to the map, you should get the updated value of region from the MKMapView object and use that to create the polygon.

```
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latCenter, lonCenter), MKCoordinateSpanMake(mapWidthY, mapWidthX));
self.radarMap.region = mapRegion;
CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinates[4];

// Get the actual region that MapKit is using
MKCoordinateRegion actualMapRegion = self.radarMap.region;
CLLocationDegrees actualLatCenter = actualMapRegion.center.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees actualLonCenter = actualMapRegion.center.longitude;
CLLocationDegrees actualLatSpan = actualMapRegion.span.latitudeDelta;
CLLocationDegrees actualLonSpan = actualMapRegion.span.longitudeDelta;

// And use that to create the polygon
coordinates[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(actualLatCenter+ actualLatSpan/2, actualLonCenter+ actualLonSpan/2);
coordinates[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(actualLatCenter+ actualLatSpan/2, actualLonCenter-actualLonSpan/2);
coordinates[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(actualLatCenter-actualLatSpan/2, actualLonCenter-actualLonSpan/2);
coordinates[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(actualLatCenter-actualLatSpan/2, actualLonCenter+ actualLonSpan/2);
self.boundaryOverlay = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coordinates count:4];
[self.radarMap addOverlay:self.boundaryOverlay];
```

I was curious about the increasing misalignment that you were seeing as you moved north. It occurred to me that you were probably using a fixed ratio for the mapWidthX and mapWidthY. MapKit uses a projection that is non-conformal. One consequence of that is that the map gets stretched in the North-South direction, with more stretching the farther you get from the equator.

If you create your region using a ratio that's correct for the equator, it will be incorrect as you move toward the poles. MKMapView will take the region you give it and display something close to it. But the farther you get from the equator, the more of an adjustment it needs to make. And the bigger the difference between the region you give it and the actual region it uses.